# KERAS: Get a SLICE of RNN timesteps with return_sequence = True

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

My questions is rather simple but seemed to be unsolved.

**Input**: (bs, timesteps, input_dim) --> Tensor("stack:0", shape=(?, **4**, 400), dtype=float32)

**Layer**:
output = LSTM(100, input_shape = (timesteps, input_feature), return_sequence = True) (input)

**Expect**: (bs, timesteps, output_dim) --> Tensor("gru_20/transpose_1:0", shape=(?, **4**, 100), dtype=float32)

**Output**: Tensor("gru_20/transpose_1:0", shape=(?, **?**, 100), dtype=float32)

Why does Keras not infer the number of timesteps, even it receives an input_shape? When I use the model summary the result it shows has the correct output shape:

---

lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 4, 100)             3232

But not during construction. So, when I want to unstacked the Tensor to a list of Tensors for every timesteps * (bs, 10) by using unstack(output, axis=1)] I receive ofc this error: ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (?, ?, 100)

Where is my mistake?

BTW. Adding TimeDistributed(Dense(100))(questions) results in the correct output dim: Tensor("time_distributed_17/Reshape_1:0", shape=(?, **4**, 100), dtype=float32) but not an option because of shared weights. If not, what is the workaround?

Comment: I do not know why this is, but, as a workaround, if you need the correct shape at the output you can enforce it with a [`Reshape`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape) layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Probably I am doing it wrong because I got an error.
Using: newoutput =  Reshape((4, 100))(output) 
should result in  (None, 4, 100)
but ERROR: ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged.
Using inference by using -1 like newoutput =  Reshape((-1, 100))(output) leads again to (?,?,100). Also not working in combination with TimeDistributed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work-around might be a multiplication by 1 (no change).

```
workaround = TimeDistributed(Lambda(lambda x: x * 1.0))(output)
```

Inference works here:

> Tensor("time_distributed_17/Reshape_1:0", shape=(?, 4, 100), dtype=float32)

Is a `TimeDistributed` layer always necessary when using `return_sequences=True`?